# Django 1.6.1, Python 3.3.2, uwsgi 2.0 -- uwsgi crashes and won't run

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, webserver, uwsgi

I compiled python 3.3.2 from source because I'm not sure how else to install python 3.3.2. Prior to compiling it I installed:

`zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libpq-dev python3-dev python-dev`

Then I setup virtualenv like usual and tried installing uwsgi through pip but it crashed with a linking error but the stack trace didn't contain any information on what was missing (this is a separate concern but if anyone is interested here's the trace https://gist.github.com/AntelopeSalad/8735358).

Someone recommend I install uwsgi from source and that compiled but then this happens when I try to run it:

https://gist.github.com/AntelopeSalad/8737279

I compiled uwsgi by downloading 2.0 by doing:

- Downloaded https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/u/uWSGI/uwsgi-2.0.tar.gz
- Unzipped it and ran `python3.3 uwsgiconfig.py --build`

My OS is Lubuntu 13.x. Any ideas?

Comment: why you installed python3-dev if you compiled python3 from sources ? You basically forced uWSGI to link with a python environment that is diffeent from what you will use when running it..

Comment: I thought in order to install python 3.x I would need the dev packages on my system. That is what a lot of tutorials said to do.

Comment: to build python you need gcc, autotools and a linker, nothing more (the debian/ubuntu build-essentials package). You have basically installed python2 and python3 to build python :) Now you have 2 python3.3 in your system, one for which you have built uwsgi and another (with different settings) for which you have created a virtualenv

Comment: I added the extra ones because I couldn't access postgres without re-compiling python with those libs. I had a problem installing something else too, maybe pip which required bz2.

So installing *-dev installs the real package too? So I did basically apt-get install python3?

That would explain why I do have 3.3.2 in /usr/bin and 3.3.2 in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: exactly, python3-dev has python3 as dependancy.

Comment: If you want to convert your comments into an answer I'll mark you as correct, thanks.