# Python3 uWSGI stops instantly

Tags: django, uwsgi

I am having a an issue where I can't get uwsgi to run on my machine. I keep getting this:

```
/usr/bin$ sudo service ppuwsgi start
>>ppuwsgi start/running, process 17452

/usr/bin$ sudo service ppuwsgi status
>>ppuwsgi stop/waiting
```

I think I might be having a similar issue as this guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486843/django-1-6-1-python-3-3-2-uwsgi-2-0-uwsgi-crashes-and-wont-run). However, I didn't install from source. I saw that the machine came with python3.4. But I did do

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python3-dev
```

and maybe even

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

I want to think I don't have python installed twice. And I have no idea how to check and see. I opened up my `usr/local/bin` and saw uwsgi and some pip stuff but no python.

Lastly, here is my `/etc/init/ppuwsgi.conf`

```
# file: /etc/init/ppuwsgi.conf 
description "uWSGI server for PingPlot"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --home /home/ubuntu/web/app/ --socket /home/ubuntu/web/ppuwsgi.sock --chmod-socket --module wsgi --pythonpath /home/ubuntu/web/ -H /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pingplot --logto /home/ubuntu/web/logs/uwsgi.log
```

The sock file and log file seem to get created as well (the log file is empty). I don't know what the deal is.

**Edit:**

So I opened up user/bin/ and here are all the python things I have.

[image: a bunch of Python stuff]

**EDIT: I LIED**

I am getting stuff in the error log. I just couldn't see it because I opened vim without sudo. Here is the error log:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.8 (64bit) on [Thu Dec 11 05:36:59 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 09 December 2014 02:42:22
os: Linux-3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014
nodename: ip-172-31-9-208
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 15925
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
chmod() socket to 666 for lazy and brave users
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/ubuntu/web/ppuwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 23:03:41)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge
ImportError: No module named site
```

Comment: Regarding the different Python versions...what do you get when you simply run `python --version` on your shell? It will tell you which version your system is using as the default. Next, you should be able to find other Python versions under `/usr/bin/...`, if any.

Comment: when I do python --version I get python2.7.6 but I also have python3 --version which gives me python3.4.0. Which one would uwsgi default to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the error log. I changed my version of Python. I uninstalled uwsgi and pip and then reinstalled it using python3 pip.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

Then I was able to get uwsgi running.

Comment: The other errors weren't relevant to the question. Just python errors.